# Can I user SiriKit with Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, sirikit

I have searched the web but haven't found how make Siri interact with my Nativescript application.
Is there a plugin or a configuration tweek available?

Comment: I don't do much iOS so can't provide a solid answer to HOW but the answer to CAN is, yes. There isn't anything that would prevent you from using SiriKit with NS. Wish I knew more iOS to provide a good sample :) Maybe this https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-homekit and Eddy's guest blog post will help some https://www.nativescript.org/blog/getting-started-with-homekit-and-nativescript on where you might get started with SiriKit